# How to make saving files in the web root folder secure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I was working on a project where i have to store documents(docx/pdf) from users. Since I'm going to be expecting thousands of them it didn't look like a good idea to store them as a blob in a SQL server and i decided to store them in the WEB root folder and record the path name in the database, but since everyone can access them i appended a GUID to the file name so it's hard to brute force the directory and get the files, is this secure enough or what can i add to make it more secure. I'm using ASP.NET core 3.1

Comment: content in the web root is public and of course not for protected data. You can create another folder to store sensitive files. Those files there can only be accessed by your server unless you expose some endpoint to support downloading the files from clients. Read more about static files https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @King King said, if you're making them available on the web, it's possible that someone may be able to access each of them. You can make this more difficult, of course, by ensuring that you use `UseStaticFiles` instead of `UseFileServer` so users will have to match on exactly the name of the file to access it (e.g. no default file handling and no directory browsing options).

Further, while it doesn't help much if you're just mapping directly to another directory, but you could host all the files themselves in a non-public folder and use the options passed to `UseStaticFiles` to reflect a different path from which to serve them as in the following. Place the following after `app.UseAuthorization()` to ensure proper authorization before accessing the files as well so at least you can log any attempted brute force operation from un-authenticated accounts.

```cs
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
  //...
  app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions {
    FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider ("/your/local/path"),
    RequestPath = "/request" //Requires a call to domain.com/request/[file] to access the file
  });
}
```